# Select source image resolution dynamically

Tags: flutter

I'm building an app where the same image can be displayed in a lot of different sizes (big on desktop/tablet and smaller on phones). I also want to take into account the device pixel density to always load the most appropriate source.

I know this is possible in HTML using the `srcset` and `sizes` attributes to specify sources and sizes but how would I do something similar in Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

Try [AspectRatio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=8&v=XcnP3_mO_Ms&feature=emb_logo), this is responsive for all sizes

```
AspectRatio(
    aspectRatio: 4 / 3, //change value here
    child: new Container(
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the display size of the image at the time of build using a `LayoutBuilder` and the device pixel density using MediaQueries.

I created a package that does just that : https://pub.dev/packages/responsive_image

Just specify your sources and the widget will take care of selecting the most appropriate source and render the image.

```dart
ResponsiveImage(
  srcSet: {
    64: "https://via.placeholder.com/64",
    128: "https://via.placeholder.com/128",
    256: "https://via.placeholder.com/256",
    512: "https://via.placeholder.com/512",
  },
  scalePreference: ScalePreference.Upper,
);
```

You can also use the builder to further customize the display of the image (for example using `cached_network_image`)

```dart
ResponsiveImage(
  srcSet: {
    256: "https://via.placeholder.com/256",
    512: "https://via.placeholder.com/512",
    1024: "https://via.placeholder.com/1024",
  },
  builder: (BuildContext context, String url) {
    return CachedNetworkImage(
      imageUrl: url,
      placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
      errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
    );
  },
);
```